# How to fix iFrame issues (iOS) in Cordova/Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova, iframe

I have an iframe in my Cordova app and I am having severe problems with it. On an iPad, the iframe isn't maximized, but only loaded in one corner. Can anybody help solve my problem...

Here's my iframe code...

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">
<iframe src="http://example.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: try giving width and height to your iframe

Answer (score 0):

I'm using iframe to load an external page in cordova 3.5 + jquery mobile project and it loads the page all right.

```
<iframe src="http://google.com/" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
```

I came across some padding issues which jquery mobile puts around its pages or divs I guess, so for the div in which I load the iframe I remove the padding as:

```
/*for devcontent to remove the default jquery mobile padding*/
#devContent{
     padding: 0em !important;
 }
```

This is loading well in iPhone and iPad both. For android there are some height issues which you must set in pixels but i'm not sure about that.